# Bounds on expectation of $X/(X^2 + c)$ with $X$ ~ Gaussian and $c > 0$

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, integration, expectation

I'm trying to compute expectation of $X / (X^2 + c)$ when $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and $c$ is some positive constant. I think this cannot be solved analytically (at least Mathematica is not able to do it), but can we get some nontrivial bounds for the expectation? We can assume that $\sigma^2 \ll \mu$ so we can focus on density near the expected value if that helps.

Comment: One trick is to use the fact that $1/s = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-s*t} dt$. Now replace $s$ by $X^2+c$. This will result in estimating an integral.

Answer (score 2):

series expansion for small $\sigma^2$ gives
$$\mathbb{E}[{X(X^2+c)^{-1}}]=\frac{{\mu}}{c+{\mu}^2}+\frac{{\mu}  \left({\mu}^2-3 c\right)}{\left(c+{\mu}^2\right)^3}{\sigma}^2+\frac{3 {\mu}  \left(5 c^2-10 c {\mu}^2+{\mu}^4\right)}{\left(c+{\mu}^2\right)^5}{\sigma}^4+{\cal O}(\sigma/\mu)^6$$